# Regression on exponent with negative datapoints

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

So, I have $n$ triplets $(x,y,w)$, where $x$ and $y$ are supposedly correlated, and $w$ is a weight factor.

The range of variables are : $ x,y \in (-\infty,\infty)$ and $w \in (0,\infty)$

Now, I want to fit a regression:
$$ y = Aw^B x$$

If $x$ and $y$ were constrained to have same sign, then it is standard linear regression
$$ log(y/x) = A^\prime +B \ log(w)$$

But I am not able to solve it for general case. Probably this is covered in standard texts but I am unable to recall if I have come across this earlier. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: You can find $A$ and $B$ in $y=Aw^Bx$’without transforming to your second equation, perhaps using nonlinear least squares.

Comment: The reason this won't be covered in standard texts--or anywhere else--is that the expression $w^B$ is not generally defined when $w$ is negative unless $B$ is a natural number.

Comment: @whuber  $w$ is positive here

Comment: I overlooked that because when $w$ is guaranteed positive, there is no special problem in fitting the model unless it's possible for $x$ and $y$ to have opposite signs.  If that's ever the case, it implies the errors in the model cannot be taken to be multiplicative and so rules out linearization *via* the logarithm. How you proceed depends on your probability model for the errors. That requires considering how $(x,y)$ is measured, as well as understanding exactly how their underlying true values might deviate from the functional form you posit. What can you tell us about these things?

Comment: $x$ is from a normal distribution.

I have plenty of data points with opposite signs. I could consider two error distributions - one independent of $x$ and second normally distributed over $x$